# how do the hover psuedo class behaves on touch screen devices

Tags: css, web, mobile, browser

On mobile devices elements having hover class activates when a user taps on them.So they behave like the active class elements. Then what's the difference between these classes for touch screen devices. Do they differ in any manner? If yes then how, if no then which one should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blocks with hover styles on touch devices are a bit of a complication.
>   **In short, they don’t really exist on these devices**. Creating fancy
>   :hover styles can really add to the browser experience and help
>   simplify your layout, but they simply **will not work on a touch device**.
>   When a tablet or smartphone user taps your hover-styled link elements,
>   the hover style shortly appears, and immediately the underlying link
>   is followed/activated.

for more information check here
https://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/how-deal-hover-touch-screen-devices